# python types in list during comprehension

Tags: python, types

I have a sql query string such as the following:

```
intro text,
id int,
description varchar(50)
```

I am trying to create a string of types, with the goal of finding pieces of text that do not match the types defined in the sql schema. The way I am extracting the types from the sql text is as follows:

```
types = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','',x.split()[1]) for x in schema] 
types = [re.sub('varchar',types.StringType,x) for x in types]
types = [re.sub('text',types.StringType,x) for x in types]
types = [re.sub('bigint',types.IntType,x) for x in types]
types = [re.sub('decimal',types.IntType,x) for x in types]
```

However the interpreter complains that

```
types = [re.sub('varchar',types.StringTypes,x) for x in types]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'StringTypes'
```

A SSCCE

With the following schema file

```
intro text,
id int,
description varchar(50)
```

and code (note, with fix as suggested by oscar below, but now with other error)

```
import csv
import sys
import re
import types

sch = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")

#---------------------------------   
# read schema
#---------------------------------     
with sch as f:
    schema = f.read().splitlines()

#---------------------------------    
# extract schema types
#---------------------------------  

foundtypes = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','',x.split()[1]) for x in schema] 
foundtypes = [re.sub('varchar',str,x) for x in foundtypes]
foundtypes = [re.sub('text',str,x) for x in foundtypes]
foundtypes = [re.sub('int',int,x) for x in foundtypes]
foundtypes = [re.sub('bigint',int,x) for x in foundtypes]
foundtypes = [re.sub('decimal',int,x) for x in foundtypes]

print foundtypes
```

I am using Python 2.7.5

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You overwrote the binding (see: [variable shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)) to the `types` [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html), in this line:

```
types = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','',x.split()[1]) for x in schema]
```

After that, `types` is no longer pointing to the module, but to a list. Just use another name in all the assignments:

```
my_types = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','',x.split()[1]) for x in schema] 
my_types = [re.sub('varchar',types.StringType,x) for x in my_types]
my_types = [re.sub('text',types.StringType,x) for x in my_types]
my_types = [re.sub('bigint',types.IntType,x) for x in my_types]
my_types = [re.sub('decimal',types.IntType,x) for x in my_types]
```

**UPDATE**

I think you overdesigned the solution, except for the first line this is not a good fit for using regular expressions. A simple `if-elif-else` will work just fine:

```
def transform(typestr):
    if typestr in ('varchar', 'text'):
        return types.StringType
    elif typestr in ('int', 'bigint', 'decimal'):
        return types.IntType
    else:
        return None

my_types = [re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', '', x.split()[1]) for x in schema] 
[transform(x) for x in my_types]
=> [<type 'str'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'str'>]
```

Comment: that worked. now i get this error: foundtypes = [re.sub('bigint',types.IntType,x) for x in foundtypes]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not '_sre.SRE_Match'

Comment: @Peyman sorry, I can't reproduce the error. Please post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) which isolates the problem

Comment: see above oscar. Note, I changed the "types.XXX" to "int/str/..." since these should be equivalent. the errors are the same.

Comment: @Peyman I believe I found the problem, instead of the actual types you should use the _string_ representation of the types. For example, in the second assignment line: `[re.sub('varchar', str(str), x) for x in foundtypes]`. After all, `sub()` expects a _string_ as a replacement, not a `type` object

Comment: Hi oscar. that works. but it pushes the problem downstream when I want to check if an object is an instance of one of foundtypes. If i uses isinstance(object,foundtype(i)), foundtype is always a string. so i am guessing regex is the wrong solution for substitution. Any suggestions what would be better? thank you Oscar

Comment: @Peyman see my update, I think that solves the issue. I hope that earned me an accept ;)

Comment: oh yes. it did indeed. thank you for all your help oscar. much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the module `types` module. Change the name of the list that you're saving to and it should work.

```
foundtypes = [re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','',x.split()[1]) for x in schema] 
foundtypes = [re.sub('varchar',types.StringType,x) for x in foundtypes]
foundtypes = [re.sub('text',types.StringType,x) for x in foundtypes]
foundtypes = [re.sub('bigint',types.IntType,x) for x in foundtypes]
foundtypes = [re.sub('decimal',types.IntType,x) for x in foundtypes]
```